# Stomp Web Socket with ActiveMQ Maximum Frame Size ERROR

Tags: javascript, websocket, jms, activemq-classic, stomp

I have a Stomp client configured to communicate with an ActiveMQ broker over the web socket protocol.

stomp.js has the following function for sending:

```
Client.prototype._transmit = function(command, headers, body) {
  var out;
  out = Frame.marshall(command, headers, body);
  if (typeof this.debug === "function") {
    this.debug(">>> " + out);
  }
  while (true) {
    if (out.length > this.maxWebSocketFrameSize) {
      this.ws.send(out.substring(0, this.maxWebSocketFrameSize));
      out = out.substring(this.maxWebSocketFrameSize);
      if (typeof this.debug === "function") {
        this.debug("remaining = " + out.length);
      }
    } else {
      return this.ws.send(out);
    }
  }
};
```

Where:

`command` is `'SEND'`,

`headers` is `{"content-length" : false}`,

and `body` is a very long stringified JSON object. (Longer than `this.maxWebSocketFrameSize`)

`maxWebSocketFrameSize = 16 * 1024;` This is set in the initialization of the client.

So this function divides my large message into multiple frames and sends them individually.

The default debug logs in stomp.js give me (in the Chrome console)

```
<<< ERROR
content-type:text/plain
message:The maximum command length was exceeded

org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolException: The maximum command length was exceeded
at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.readHeaderLine(StompWireFormat.java:158)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.readLine(StompWireFormat.java:148)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.parseAction(StompWireFormat.java:181)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.unmarshal(StompWireFormat.java:98)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.unmarshal(StompWireFormat.java:62)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.StompSocket.onMessage(StompSocket.java:76)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455$WSFrameHandler.onFrame(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:722)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketParserRFC6455.parseNext(WebSocketParserRFC6455.java:349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.handle(WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:627)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And the ActiveMQ console window shows:

```
WARN | Transport Connection to: StompSocket_721080149 failed: java.io.IOException
WARN | Exception occurred processing:
null
null 
null
null 
null
null
null
```

If I put a breakpoint on `out` each frame is exactly what is should be according to the code. A substring of `body`. I'm not sure if this is correct, or if it should be restructured to have its own command etc.

If this is the correct behavior, then maybe it's with my ActiveMQ broker configuration:

```
<transportConnector name="websocket" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:24511/>
```

Works great for any messages shorter than 16 * 1024.

I did change the above transportConnector configuration to:

```
<transportConnector name="websocket" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:24511?websocket.maxTextMessageSize=9999999"/>
```

and manually changed `maxWebSocketFrameSize = 16 * 1024` to `maxWebSocketFrameSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024` in stomp.js. This gave me more than enough frame size and worked perfectly.

I'm curious to know if this is an ok solution, or if splitting the large message into multiple frames would be the more desired method. If the latter (or not), why are the frames showing as `null` in ActiveMQ?